# So i have been learning python for few days now, but having a hard time trying to understand the changes of boolean value in the program,

Tags: python

```
command = ""
started = False 
while True:
    command = input("> ").lower()
    if command == "start":
        if started: 
            print("Car is already started!")
        else:
            started = True
            print("Car started... Ready to go!")
    elif command == "stop":
        if  started == False:
            print("Car is already stopped!")
        else:
            started = False
            print("Car stopped!")
    elif command  == "help":
        print("""
 start - to start the car
 stop - to stop car
 quit - to exit
        """)
    elif command == "quit":
        break
    else:
        print("I don't understand that!"
```

unable to understand when is the boolean value of started is changing in the whole program. a little help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an application of boolean flags to control  the program.
Now: `started = False`. So, if the user inputs `start`, it will first check if `started==True`, as seen in `if started`. If it is True, then it will print `Car is already started!`. If not, `started = True` is updated. Now, `started` is True. So, even if you input `start` it will print `Car is already started!`.

The same is applied in the bottom part. Only the difference is that it is inversed. `if started==False`, `"Car is already stopped!"` is printed, else `started = False` is updated, which can only be changed when you input `start`

```
    if command == "start":
        if started: 
            print("Car is already started!")
        else:
            started = True
            print("Car started... Ready to go!")
    elif command == "stop":
        if  started == False:
            print("Car is already stopped!")
        else:
            started = False
            print("Car stopped!")
```

Comment: thanks for the help, really appreciate it!!